# replace not found image with no-thumb.png

Tags: php

i use codeigniter. i build in **localhost**

i call image link from database like : http://**example.com**/person1.png, http://example.com/person2.png

IF database said NULL or EMPTY, i will replace image by no-thumb.png

if that image is stored in my drive (localhost) i can use is_file()

> And my problem is : database said that image is exist as
>   http://example.com/person1.png, but actually, the image is not exist
>   i want to display 20 data in each page.

i can check the link using, fil_get_content, get_header or curl, like this,

```
function url_exists($url) {
    if (!$fp = curl_init($url)) return false;
    return true;
}
```

but i need to dowload 20 file for checking purpose which not cool,

is there any elegant/best way to solve this problem?

for demo, i upload my screenshot
[image: you can see my problem in the first row]
my problem is in the first row (red circle).

Thanks for any help. i will appreciate that

Comment: Could you provide the code which generates the user list (picture)?

Comment: have you tried using [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)

Comment: Does you file exists on the same server where you code is running? If so then you have to store the relative urls to the server and go with file_exists  . If not then check it on the client side by using javascript.

Comment: file_exists is only work in local storage.

Comment: @AmanRawat as i explain in question. my web is in localhost , and the image host is in example.com.

Comment: @AmanRawat hmm.. client side.. i think thats the potential answer. ill doing it, thanks bro

Comment: ok so you have to go with the javascript to check the broken link and replace those with you default image. Chek this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images

Comment: thanks my friend. i can do that with jquery. but i will check your link first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your images are on another server then it is very time consuming process to check image exists or not on server side.

So you shoud go with the clint side check for the broken links and place an default image for it.

Check this link will help you to do that
[jQuery/JavaScript to replace broken images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images)